# Devextreme built in themes handling in a react application being ignored

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, themes, devextreme

I am trying to figure out how to handle setting themes which come with devextreme.  I have tried a lot of different things but none seem to work.  I am using devextreme 23.1.3.  I am using the built in dx themes.  I am using the devextreme app framework with react.  I have a simple page I am testing which has a datagrid on it which imports no scss or css files.  In the index.html I have link tag which has the following syntax

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/23.1.5/css/dx.contrast.css" />
```

I ran it in chrome and checked in the network tab.  I saw the above style sheets were being loaded:

```
https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/23.1.5/css/dx.darkmoon.css
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700
https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notokufiarabic.css
```

The site did not change anywhere to the darkmoon theme.

The simple page looks like this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import DataGrid, { HeaderFilter, Editing, Paging, Pager, FilterRow, SearchPanel, StateStoring, Column, Scrolling } from 'devextreme-react/data-grid';
import {stringify} from "flatted";
//import 'devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css';
//import './meters.scss';

const MetersPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // Manage the data state
  const [filterValues, setFilterValues] = useState("");
  const dataGridRef = useRef(null);

  /*
  const applyFilter = () => {
    let values = filterValues.replace(/\s+/g, "").split(',');
    if (dataGridRef.current) {
      dataGridRef.current.instance.columnOption("EXTNL_MTR_ID", "filterValues", values);
    }
  };

  const clearFilter = () => {
    setFilterValues(""); // Clear the filter values
    if (dataGridRef.current) {
      dataGridRef.current.instance.columnOption("EXTNL_MTR_ID", "filterValues", null);
    }
  };
*/

  const fetchData = () => {
    // Make an API call to fetch data from the Django backend
    fetch('https://vm-devmdms02/meters2/')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const handleSave = (changes: any) => {
    // Clone the changes object to avoid modifying the original object
    const clonedChanges = { ...changes };

    // Remove properties with circular references
    const serializedData = stringify(clonedChanges);

    // Make an API call to save the modified changes in the Django backend
    fetch('https://vm-devmdms02/meters2/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: serializedData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(() => {
        // On success, fetch updated data and refresh the grid
        fetchData();
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(); // Fetch data on component mount
  }, []);

  return (
  <div>
    < DataGrid
      ref={dataGridRef}
      dataSource={data} 
      showBorders={true} 
      remoteOperations={true}
      onSaving={handleSave}
    >
      <Editing
          mode="cell"
          allowAdding={true}
          allowUpdating={true}
          allowDeleting={true}
          useIcons={true}/>
        <FilterRow visible={true} />
        <HeaderFilter allowSearch={true} />
        <Column
          dataField='DMI_DEVICE'
          caption='DMI_DEVICE'
        />
        <Column
          dataField='EXTNL_MTR_ID'
          caption='EXTNL_MTR_ID'
        />
        <Column
          dataField='DEVICE_NAME'
          caption='DEVICE_NAME'
        />
        <Column
          dataField='EIS_DEV_TYPE'
          caption='EIS_DEV_TYPE'
        />

        <Column
          dataField='DMI_RCDR_SP_NM'
          caption='DMI_RCDR_SP_NM'
        />
        <Column
          dataField='DMI_DP_MDM'
          caption='DMI_DP_MDM'
        />
        <Column
          dataField='DMI_DP'
          caption='DMI_DP'
        />
        <Column
          dataField='DMI_MTR'
          caption='DMI_MTR'
        />
        <Column
          dataField='DMI_MTR_CFG'
          caption='DMI_MTR_CFG'
        />
        <SearchPanel visible={true}/>
        <Paging defaultPageSize={10} />
        <StateStoring enabled={true} type={"localStorage"}/>
        <Pager showPageSizeSelector={true} showInfo={true} />
      </ DataGrid>
    </ div>
  );
};

export default MetersPage;
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need provide more information about your setup, such as the following:
What version of DevExtreme are you using?, 
What version of React are you using?
How the way are you bundling your app?
Are you using any other CSS libraries or frameworks in your app?

Comment: Thanks Naandalist, I am using DevExtreme version 23.1.3, React version 18.2.0, I am using BabelFish to bundle the app, I am only using the css and libraries which came with React and DevExtreme.  I am using the DevExtreme app framework.

Comment: can you create a small reproducible example?

Comment: Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). such as on `codesandbox`